# Kafka and Heterogeneous Messages

Tags: architecture, avro, apache-kafka

I was doing some research about **Kafka** and **Avro**, and I have a question on how to handle heterogeneous messages with **Kafka**.

Let's imagine we have two **Avro** schemas: `EmailSent` and `UserLoggedIn`. What is the best way with Kafka to consume them?

1. Create *a topic per schema*? But it sounds like a bad idea if we have a lot more schemas...
2. Store the *schema name* (or an identifier like `email_sent` or `user_logged_in`) *in the key* of the `KeyedMessage` and let every consumer filter by the key? But every consumers will have to consume all the events and it may be an overhead...
3. Something else :)

I hope that my quesion is clear. Thanks in advance for your help!

Cheers,

Radium.

Answer (score 0):

`1st Approach`: I think, this can be done in single topic. You can separate out these two schema datasets on the basis of partition in your Topic. Suppose you create 4 partitions in your topic. Write email_sent in 1 and 2. Write user_logged_in in 3 and 4. 
One consumer group will subscribe to 1 and 2. 2nd consumer group will subscribe to 3 and 4. In this, no unnecessary IO is done.
`2nd Approach`: Create two separate topics.

Comment: I just read that LinkedIn use more than 32000 topics so the first approach sounds better. What do you think?)